# Autocomplete results on the top of input

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am stuck on the very basic problem. I want to see results of autocomplete above the text input (most similiar result just above the text input, less farther). Is it possible?

I want to use autocomplete function from W3Schools here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete (can't copy code because of limit code per description...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you shared, you just need to update the property for `.autocomplete-items`. Change `top: 100%;`to `bottom: 100%;` and you'll get the search results of autocomplete above the text input.

Comment: Thank You! I thought it was something simple :)

Comment: If it helped, kindly upvote the answer and mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks!